# Help me find a certain type of crystallographic notation

Tags: geology, geochemistry, crystallography

I was looking through wikipedia a few weeks ago while half asleep, reading articles about rocks and their chemical compositions. I then came across a certain crystallographic notation which I had not seen before, encoding (if I remember correctly) the configuration of tetrahedral complexes in the crystal. There also were curly brackets involved. Sadly, I was already too out of it to remember the name, and subsequent wikipedia journeys revealed nothing. Did I dream this? If not, what is this notation?